# Trying to install Kali on my Pi 3

Tags: sd-card, kali

I'm a beginner with the Raspberry Pi and know little about it, so please bear with me. I was trying to install Kali onto my Pi, so I used my PC to format an SD card and load what I assume is the image file (extension .img.xz) onto it using the Win32DiskImager. When I inserted the SD card into my Pi and plug it in, however, it wouldn't boot up.

Is there something wrong with the way that I'm trying to load the card? And is there any better way to install Kali -- perhaps using NOOBS?

Comment: Did you extract the `.img`  from the `.img.xz` first?

Answer (score 1):

xz extension means that it's a compressed file. find a program such as winzip to uncompress the .img file. that's your disk image that you want to burn.

Comment: Alternatively, Etcher says it handles .xz files directly.  I haven't tested this. https://etcher.io/

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to look after:

1. Make sure you have a fast SD-card. Depending on the OS you need a
   fast, or very fast SD-card. You are booting an OS with a SD-card,
   it's not rocket science, but still asks a lot of the SD-card.
2. Make sure you have at least 8Gb
3. Make sure you copied the RPi-version of Kali Linux. [Here](https://www.offensive-security.com/kali-linux-arm-images/) you find
   all versions. You need a smaller version compatible with ARM.